# Java - explanation for using " | "?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and learning java. In recent guide, i came across the method to toggle password field to normal text field.

**Can someone please explain use of `|` in this statement ?**

```
final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);

if(passTog.isChecked())
{
   input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
}else {
   input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
}
```

Any help regarding this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

*I need to know how this* **Bitwise OR** *is working infact here ?*
 Here is complete code to avoid ambiguity regarding the variables:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    Button checkCommand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

    passTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(passTog.isChecked()){
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            }else {
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: [Bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

Comment: Why was he majorly downvoted?

Comment: I'm sure somewhere I saw a manual...

Comment: I am new to Java - Dont Downvote please

Comment: @JohnStrickler - Because... Why on earth would you ask this question without googling first?  (regardless of your level of experience) For the record, I did **not** downvote.  Though I'm tempted to... My gut reaction would be to google ["_java operators_")[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: @jahroy: Actually i have an idea of Bitwise OR operator and i also googled that - What i am unable to understand is it's use here ? input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Comment: Like I said... I didn't downvote.  But I can _easily_ understand the rationale.  Not sure what's to misunderstand... `|` is an operator.  In that code it _operates_ on two variables.  I'd consider writing a quick test program to see exactly what it does to those two variables.  If you need us to _tell_ you what/why it does, you should provide the values of the two strings.

Comment: Alright - p.s i have edited my question and added whole class code.

Comment: Now that I look closer, it looks like the variables are part of a class from the Android libraries.  I suggest reading the documentation for `InputType`, where you will certainly find some info.

Comment: That's part of ``InputType``

Comment: Now that I look at the documentation, I'm downvoting and voting to close.  It's all spelled out right there.  Please learn to consult the documentation when you have a question about anything programming related.  The info is almost always there (if you're willing to read).

Comment: i am into documentation.... Thanks for your support & help :)

Comment: **From the very top of the documentation:** "_A password field with with the password visible to the user:
inputType = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD_"  It's literally **the first** thing mentioned on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_TEXT).

Comment: Thankyou for Support - Much appreciated 
And personally i consider it my mistake not consulting the doc first.

Comment: A request - undo downvote please

Comment: Absoutely not.  This question is the epitome of "_shows no effort_".  People who search with similar questions should find the Android documentation, not this question.

Comment: Like i said - Apologies.

Comment: I understand and fully support and that's why confessed my mistake and requested to undo downvote - that can also help many. Trust me.
p.s "Apologies" was for some reason.. Anyways.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33727/discussion-between-shumail92-and-jahroy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That code isn't using `|` in an `if` statement.  It's using it in the body of an `if` statement which is very different.  When used there, it's a [bitwise-or](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operation.  **Edit:** @RohitJain has provided a much better link than mine in his comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

---

*If* it were used in an `if` statement like so:

```
if (foo() | bar())
```

that means "don't short circuit".  If `foo()` returned "true" it will still evaluate `bar()`.  If you used `||` and `foo()` returns "true", it won't evaluate `bar()` because it knows the result of the `if` statement will be "true" no matter what else happens.

---

For your specific question, you can see the possible values of [`InputType` here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT = Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD = Constant Value: 128 (0x00000080)
```

Using [this tool](http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/), I've calculated the result of a bitwise or will be: 129.  To see how to get that value, read the wikipedia article above.

Comment: Can you please explain how ``|`` is working in that statement ?
``input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);``

Comment: I'd need to know the values of `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` and `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` to be able to do that.  But you can use this link to get the general idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR

Comment: What class is `input`?  I'd need to know that to answer that.

Comment: ``input`` is actually a variable 
``final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);``

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Now i understand it fully.... And i consider it my mistake not consulting the Doc first...

Answer (score 1):

That's bitwise OR Operator - See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) for details

Answer (score 1):

```
|  is a Bitwise inclusive OR
|| is a Conditional-OR
```

A bitwise OR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the logical inclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 or the second bit is 1 or both bits are 1; otherwise, the result is 0. For example:

```
   0101 (decimal 5)
OR 0011 (decimal 3)
 = 0111 (decimal 7)
```

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) out.

Comment: `|` is also non-short circuited conditional OR

Comment: Thanks. I have a good idea of Bitwise OR - Studied in Digital Logic Design subject. What i am unable to understand is it's use here ?
``input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);``

Comment: Very strange usage tbh, it looks like its setting the input type to be whatever results in bitwise combining the `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` and `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`. It looks like `InputType` must be an `enum` so I guess it allows you to work with more complex input types without having to include them in `InputType`? Possibly a way to evaluate types in a situation where there could be millions of potencial types that can't be included in the `enum`?

Answer (score 1):

The "|" symbol is defined as bitwise inclusive OR

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

The | (bitwise inclusive OR) operator compares the values (in binary format) of each operand and yields a value whose bit pattern shows which bits in either of the operands has the value 1. If both of the bits are 0, the result of that bit is 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

Source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05bitiore.htm

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should always do is consult the documentation.

Here is a [link to the documentation for `InputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Here is **the first thing on the page**:

```
A password field with with the password visible to the user:

    inputType = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
```

---

It's literally the **third sentence on the page**.

Answer (score 0):

| means bitwise OR

|| means logical OR

Comment: Are you sure? There is more than one logical OR

Comment: huh? I don't understand what's the other logical OR?

Answer (score 0):

The `|` is BITWISE OR'ing the constants `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` and `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`. I'm assuming that those two constants are ints used to identify internal types the `EditText` object cares about, given the formatting, but it could be any variable type. If you *really* want to know *exactly* what it's doing, you would need to know the data type of `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, but we can assume thanks common practices of Java code that it is sticking constants together for a comparison later.